# Hide a dynamic table based on sql return value using getElementById-Javascript/PHP

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to hide a dynamic table based on SQL return value using `getElementById`.

I currently can insert and display data in a dynamic table. When there is no result, the data will not display (which is working fine), and when there is a result the data will display (which works fine also). But I still need to hide the table when there is no result found because there is a delete button in the delete column which always appears even though there is no data.

So I would prefer the entire table to disappear when there is no result returned by the query and vice versa to make it clean. I've tried using all kinds of ways such as:

`mysqli_num_rows($result)==0`, 
`if($result)`,
`if($_SESSION['idadv']=='')`,
`if(empty($_SESSION['idadv']))`

I've changed my script several times and still am having problems solving this for several days.

**Examples**

```
    function hide()//example
    {
        if(//result return 0 proceed with below)
        document.getElementById("tabledata").style.display="inline";
       if(//result true proceed with below)
        document.getElementById("tabledata").style.display="none";}



    <?php

    <div id="tabledata" style="display: inline;">
    <?php
    if(!$result){
        die('bro_you_have_error:'.mysqli_connect_error());
    }

if($result){
    echo "<table id='tableone'>";
    echo "<tr><td>hello</td></tr>
    echo"</table>
}

      ?>
  </div>
```

more code below

```
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
echo "<tr><td></tr></td>";
echo "<table cellpadding=10 border=0 id='secondtable'>";
echo "<tr><td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Membership"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Title"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Location"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Phone"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Picture"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Date Reg"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Delete?"."</td></tr>";
while( $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$showdateua=$row['dateua'];
$showdateua=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($showdateua));
//$showdateua=$row['dateua'];
//$showdateua=date('d.m.Y"');
//$row['dateua']=date("d.m.Y");
echo "<tr><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".$_SESSION['membership']=$row['membership'].
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".$_SESSION['title']=$row['title'].
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".$_SESSION['location']=$row['location'].
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".$_SESSION['adphone']=$row['adphone'].
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".
'<img src="'.$_SESSION['image1']=$row['image1'].'"alt="No image"style="width:100px;height:100px;"/>'.
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".$_SESSION['dateua']=$showdateua.
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>"."<a href=\"rundelup.php?idadv=".$row['idadv']."\">".'<input type="submit" name="Delete"  value="Delete" id="Delete">'."</a></td></tr>";
/*"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>"."<a href='kransjp.php?idadv=".$row['idadv']."'>"."Delete"."</a></td></tr>";*/
//echo $_SESSION['idadv']=$row['idadv'];
}
echo "</table>";
}
else
{echo "no records";
}
//}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't write the table tag outside your sql result.

Do something like this:

```
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "<table id='tableone'>";

    // add rows/columns dynamically here

    echo "</table>";
}?>
```

Hence table will not be created if there is 0 rows from sql query.
If you want a table to be created even if there is 0 row from sql query (hidden table), than add else to the above code:

```
else{
   echo "<table id='tableone' style='display:none'>";
   echo "<tr><td>hello</td></tr>
   echo "</table>
}
```

Comment: If you wan't this to happen by javascript, then add a script tag anywhere after the table is created and call your `hide()` function from there.

<script> hide();</script>

Comment: I tried..but it just keeps popping up..the delete button and the table still there.i can't figure it out why..:-(

Comment: how do i put the $result from sql query into the function .getElementById?i have example above..but i don't know how to call the variable $result.

Comment: The code you have provided, that doesn't contain any code for any delete button... Provide more code.

Comment: it's just a sample code above..in one of the columns in the table it looks like this.."</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>"."<a href=\"rundelup.php?idadv=".$row['idadv']."\">".'<input type="submit" name="Delete"  value="Delete" id="Delete">'."</a></td></tr>";

Comment: my table is quite long.. so i just shortened it above to make it clean and easy to read.

Comment: the table is not suppose to appear when the condition is met. the data works fine according to condition. the only problem is the table. The table is quite stubborn to disappear.

Comment: I provided more codes above. tqs btw for your help.